# Displaying <div> in between two elements of a separate hierarchy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div style="background-color: blue">
    <div style="color: red">
        some content some content some content some content 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="highlight" style="top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 40px; 
                           background-color: yellow; position: fixed">
</div>
```

[**on jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/gfcmwjq9/)

---

It looks like this:

[image: Current result]

What I want to do is to visually put the `#highlight` `<div>` between the blue background and the text. Here's what I want it to look like:

[image: Desired result]

---

I am using this weird `<div>` hierarchy as in my real-life scenario I'm using JQuery to move `#highlight` with some mouse/keyboard events. I also have no control over the hierarchy of the `<div>`s containing the text.

I need `#highlight`'s `position` to either be `fixed` or `absolute`.

**Is there any way I can achieve my current result without changing the HTML structure?** I've attempted using `z-index`, but it doesn't work as the hierarchy structure has priority over it. I am open to any kind of dirty hack involving JavaScript/JQuery.

Comment: re-parent #highlight on position move?

Comment: @Griffin: sounds tough - the actual HTML structure is slightly more complicated. I would have to check the hierarchy at a particular position (mouse cursor), and figure out where to place `#highlight`.

Comment: Am I right to assume you're moving #highlight to the position of the element it should sit under? If so you already have the element, find its parent and put #highlight there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the content `div`, set `z-index:1` and `position:relative`.

```html
<div style="background-color: blue;">
  <div style="color: red; z-index: 1;position:relative;">
    some content some content some content some content
  </div>
</div>

<div id="highlight" style="top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 40px; background-color: yellow; position: fixed;">
</div>
```

Comment: For some reason I cannot get this to work in my real scenario - is there anything you can think of that could prevent this approach from working?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo possibly interference from other selectors. You could try setting `position:relative !important` although it is hard to know without inspecting the DOM. Is there a way to view the real scenario?